# How to implement soft hyphen in Android w/ React Native Text

Tags: android, react-native, hyphenation, soft-hyphen

```
<Text>
Aufmerksamkeits{'\u00AD'}defizit
</Text>
```

This leads iOS to

> Aufmerksamkeits-
> defizit

But on Android to

> Aufmerksamkeitsd
> efizit

So it seems that Android ignores the given soft hyphen. How can I make this work on Android as well?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use soft hyphen use **\u00AD** in strings, e.g.:

`<string name="einzelfahrt_name">Einzelfahrrad\u00ADkarte</string>`

In order to make this working though, in your TextView, you have to add:

```
android:hyphenationFrequency="full"
```

Comment: where one need to add "android:hyphenationFrequency"?
please provide example

Comment: In React Native this option should be set as a property:
`<Text android_hyphenationFrequency="full">Einzelfahrrad\u00ADkarte</Text>`

This worked for me! But make sure you have React Native version above the 0.65.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it seems that Android ignores soft hyphens.

The only workaround I could think of is, **only on Android**, to replace the `\u00AD` with `\u200B`. It's known as [zero-width-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), and it would properly break the words where expected, although it would not show any hyphenation character. You would end up with:

```
Aufmerksamkeits
defizit
```

Not the perfect solution, but at least it will not break words at random positions.